# Azure Copy blobs from one container to another in same storage account using rest api and php

Tags: php, azure, authentication, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy blob from one container to another in the same storage account. The documentation of azure rest api is not clear and does not say how to copy from source container to destination container also how to copy blobs from one storage account to another storage account.

I have tried to copy blob using the below code its throws an error saying "*AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.*"

```
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$account_name = "accname";
$destcontainername = "destcontainer";
$blobname = "blob.png";
$sourcecontainer = "sourcecontainer";    
$account_key = "asdf";

$canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-copy-source:https://".$account_name.".blob.core.window‌​s.net/".$sourcecontainer."/".$blobname."\n‌​x-ms-version:2015-04‌​-05";
$canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name/$destcontainername/$blobname";


$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'PUT';                     /*HTTP Verb*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Encoding*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Language*/  
$arraysign[] = 1;                        /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-MD5*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Type*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Date*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Modified-Since */  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-None-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Range*/  
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedHeaders;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

$stringtosign = implode("\n", $arraysign);
$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$account_name.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($account_key), true));

$endpoint = 'https://'.$account_name.'.blob.core.windows.net';
$url = $endpoint.'/'.$containername.'/blob.png'; 

$headers = [
    'x-ms-copy-source:https://'.$account_name.'.blob.core.window‌​s.net/'.$sourcecontainer.'/'.$blobname.'',
    //"x-ms-date:{$date}",
    'x-ms-version:2015-04-05',
    'Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata',
    'Accept-Charset:UTF-8',
    'Content-Length:1',
    "Authorization:{$signature}"
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);        

echo '<pre>';print_r($response);
```

Comment: `x-ms-copy-source` value should be same in `$headers` and in `$canonicalizedHeaders`. In both places it should be the URL of the source blob.

Comment: I tried having same x-ms-copy-source in both places but still it doesn't work gives the same auth error

Comment: One more thing....your request headers in `$canonicalizedHeaders` must be alphabetically sorted. So it should be `$canonicalizedHeaders  = "x-ms-copy-source:https://".$account_name.".blob.core.windows.net/".$containername."/".$blobname."\nx-ms-version:2015-04-05";`

Comment: I tried it doesn't work. Gives the same error message "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

Comment: Will it be possible for you to update your question with the latest code you're using. I am thinking you're missing something very minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The request header `x-ms-date` is required. It also needs presenting
  in `$canonicalizedHeaders`.
- If the request body is none, you can set `Content-Length` to `0` in
  request headers. Then set the `Content-Length` part of the
  `$stringtosign` to an empty string when using version **2015-02-21**
  or later.

Please try the following code:

```
<?php

$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$account_name = "accname";
$destcontainername = "destcontainer";
$blobname = "blob.png";
$sourcecontainer = "sourcecontainer";    
$account_key = "asdf";

$canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-copy-source:https://".$account_name.".blob.core.windows.net/".$sourcecontainer."/".$blobname."\nx-ms-date:$date\nx-ms-version:2015-04-05";
$canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name/$destcontainername/$blobname";

$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'PUT';                     /*HTTP Verb*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Encoding*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Language*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-MD5*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Type*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Date*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Modified-Since */  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-None-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Range*/  
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedHeaders;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

$stringtosign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$account_name.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($account_key), true));

$endpoint = 'https://'.$account_name.'.blob.core.windows.net';
$url = $endpoint.'/'.$destcontainername.'/'.$blobname;

$headers = [
    'x-ms-copy-source:https://'.$account_name.'.blob.core.windows.net/'.$sourcecontainer.'/'.$blobname,
    "x-ms-date:{$date}",
    'x-ms-version:2015-04-05',
    'Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata',
    'Accept-Charset:UTF-8',
    'Content-Length:0',
    "Authorization:{$signature}"
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);        

echo '<pre>';print_r($response);
```

Comment: So copy blob from one container to another in the same storage account is working fine. How would i do it for copy blob from one storage account to another in the same subscription?